# "Double depth" dimension definition in crossfilter

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Let's assume I have the same set of data than the dc.js example [here](https://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/) but with a second subdivision. For example, instead of having the moves by day, I have them by day and individual stocks.

I would like to recreate the days by fluctuation graph. Which dimension and grouping should I use in the definition of the new graph ?

Comment: Do you mean, by creating another graph to filter the others by stock, or do you mean creating multiple graphs for each stock?

Comment: @Gordon I want to recreate the exact same graph with the only difference being that I now have several records per day (the individual stocks components of the index) instead of only one (the move of the index).

Comment: I'm probably returning to this too late, but do you mean a stacked bar or line chart?

Comment: @Gordon I mean the bar chart. I have done the graph using d3.js in the end and rewritten the "interactive" part myself.

Comment: ah well, thanks for following up.  stacked bars (and series charts in general) aren't entirely intuitive in dc.js, but a number of us are working on it.  please follow up on the mailing list if you have any suggestions.